# Writing Latex onto Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\rm log \: M_*$')

plt.ylabel(r’$\rm log \: M_{\bullet}$')
```

The x axis is able to be printed correctly.
However, the y axis has an error. What's the cause for that error?

Comment: Typo in ylabel, wrong sign after "r", you type apostrophe symbol instead of single quote .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I take the Arial's answer in order to give a general solution, you have a wrong typo in the y line.

You write :

```
plt.ylabel(r’$\rm log \: M_{\bullet}$')
```

But, after the r, you made `’` instead of `'`

So, you just have to write :

```
plt.ylabel(r'$\rm log \: M_{\bullet}$')
```

And your problem is solved ;)